# Origin of "That's what she said"?

Tags: idioms, pop-culture

*That's what she said* is a saying that flips a normal statement into a sexual one. Example:

> "If you blow it too much, it'll explode" [A balloon]
>   **That's what she said!**

How did this phrase come about?

Comment: Ahah good question, I didn't think of it...

Comment: Popularised by *Wayne's World* [according to Know Your Meme](http://knowyourmeme.com/memes/thats-what-she-said) but possibly not the origin.

Comment: There's also the old idiom "That's all she wrote!"  There may be some connection.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I reckon its origin is the [phrase](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/as_the_actress_said_to_the_bishop) "As the actress said to the bishop". This means:

> used to highlight a sexual ambiguity in an innocent remark

This was then possibly shortened to "That's what she said".:

> **"Said the actress to the bishop"**, sometimes **"as the actress said to the bishop"**, or simply **"that's what she said..."**

Wayne's World was the first documented recording of the usage of "That's what she said,", but I reckon "As the actress said to the bishop" influenced it a lot.

Answer (score 8):

*That's what she said* seems to be a simplification of the phrase *said the actress to the bishop*, used with similar implications.  The phrase dates back to at least 1928, according to the [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Said_the_actress_to_the_bishop), as it was a common saying of the character Simon Templar of  "The Saint" mystery novels, the first of which was published in that year.

Answer (score 7):

I don't know about *ancient*, but it's apparently quite old according to Edmond G. Addeo in his 1973 *[EgoSpeak](http://books.google.com/books?id=BjkBAAAAMAAJ&q=%22that%27s%20what%20she%20said%22&dq=%22that%27s%20what%20she%20said%22&hl=en&ei=Q00JTuOaDKbZ0QH-sM12&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=3&ved=0CDsQ6AEwAg)*:

> The cheapest shot of all, of course, is the ancient one-liner, "That's what she said." This reply can be used after virtually any remark, however innocent, and the speaker can summon up some hint of double-entendre.